# Print func didn't print all itmes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a swift file Data.swift

```
extension NSDate {

convenience init(dateString: String) {
    let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    dateStringFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
    let date = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:date!)
}

   func getDatePart() -> String {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")

    return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
   } 
}


class GDate {

let image : String
let name : String
let date: String

init(gImage : String, gName : String, gDate: String) {
    self.name = gName
    self.image = gImage
    self.date = NSDate(dateString: gDate).getDatePart()
   }
}

struct Data {

    let places = [
    GDate(gImage: "image.png", gName: "USA", gDate: "04/26/2016"),
    GDate(gImage: "image2.png", gName: "FAR", gDate: "03/26/2016"),
    GDate(gImage: "image3.png", gName: "UK", gDate: "02/26/2016"),
    GDate(gImage: "image4.png", gName: "GER", gDate: "01/26/2016")
]
}
```

in the tableView in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GamesViewCell

    let gD = Data()
    let entry = gD.places[indexPath.row]
    let gDate = entry.date
    let image = UIImage(named: entry.image)
    cell.gameImageView.image = image
    cell.gameNameLabel.text = entry.name
    print(gDate)

    return cell
```

in the debuger it only print the first and second date and ignore the rest ?!
"same for the names if I used it instead of the dates"

[the debuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eoT4.png)

Comment: Check your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` data source method.

Comment: it return gD.places.count

Comment: You may also print indexPath, i guess need to scroll down to other cells will be display.

Comment: "dequeueReusableCell" is used when you want to re-use the cell instead of creating a new one...
Now, depending on your size of a cell, "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method is called twice... 
That is why only two items were printed...
Now as you scroll down, new cells will be created, re-using the above cells...Which will then print newly loaded items...